# Concatenate varchar[]'s in PostgreSQL, keeping distinct values

Tags: postgresql, psql

I've got a database containing network assets, each of which can have multiple hostnames. Sometimes, a we'll mistakenly create two records for the same machine, and then later have to "merge" these assets. Part of this is combining their lists of hostnames.

My current solution involves setting the `hostnames` field of the merged asset to the following select:

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT host)
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(hostnames)
  FROM asset
  WHERE asset.id IN (?, ?)
) AS bothassets(host);
```

(See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0e19b/5))

Is there a cleaner way to represent the same "unique array values" logic in PSQL? The order of the combined array doesn't matter to me, but I can't have it contain the same value twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is much cleaner way.

Only a little bit shorter:

```
SELECT ARRAY(
  SELECT DISTINCT unnest(hostnames)
  FROM asset
  WHERE asset.id IN (?, ?)
  -- ORDER BY 1
);
```